# Compile Eclipse Project With Ant

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, ant, project, compilation

I don't have eclipse on my system at all, but I have on my hands an eclipse project (flex) that I would like to compile and I was wondering if there was any way to do it with minimal to no changes having to be made. Is this possible?

Comment: I just changed my answer to propose some possibilities for Eclipse **Flex** projects.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a full *automatic* process which would take a **Flex** Eclipse project and generate the `build.xml`.

You could try and take advantage of your eclipse environment to write a **[ant builder](http://www.roseindia.net/flex/compiling_flex_on_eclipse.shtml)**:

[image]

[image]

---

You can also try **[flex2ant](http://www.flex2ant.org/index.html)** to add a specific Ant task to the Ant installation that is part of the Eclipse IDE, therefore making this task visible to the Eclipse environment.

That would facilitate the manual process mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, but that's for java only I believe, this is a flex project. :/

Comment: @Confused: Updated your question's tags to help make this clearer. Otherwise, I would have suggested ant4eclipse BTW.